# Jsoup formElement.submit().post() not submimting the value specified

Tags: java, html, button, html-parsing, jsoup

I got this `HTML` that i want to parse. I want to submit my own value in an `<input>` tag and to submit it and get the next `HTML` document.

**The template i parse is:**

```
     *  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="search-collapse">
     *
     *      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right search" method="get" action="http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php" role="search">
     *          <div class="input-group">  
     *      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="q" id="q">
     *          <span class="input-group-btn">
     *              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
     *          </span>
     *          </div>   
     *      </form>
     *
     *  </div>
```

My code takes me to a **different** document but not the one i entered his value for.

**MyCode:**

```
    // Get to <form class="navbar-form navbar-right search" method="get" action="http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php" role="search">
    FormElement formElement = htmlPage.getHtmlDocument().select("form.navbar-form.navbar-right.search").forms().get(0);

    // Set my searched lyrics in the <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="q" id="q">
    formElement.select("input[name=q]").val(searchedLyrics);

    // Get the HTML document after my searched lyrics applied
    HtmlPage searchResultDocument = new HtmlPage(formElement.submit().post());

    System.out.println(searchResultDocument.getHtmlDocument().text());
```

in the searchedResultDocument i get the same page as before and after the value submit.

What am i doing wrong?

Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a GET request, not POST:

```
HtmlPage searchResultDocument = new HtmlPage(formElement.submit().get());
```

Note that you can visit the search results page directly by navigating to the:

```
http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=your_search_query
```

Comment: How do i make a `GET` request? Thank you. And about the note i know that :). I just want to practice my `HTML` parsing skills.